# Explanation of typecasting of pointer in C++

Tags: c++, class, casting, private, encapsulation

I do not understand the two lines mentioned below in the code that I have provided here. Why I need to use `int*`? How I am accessing the private variable? I am not sure what I am doing with these two lines. Please explain in detail.

**Problematic lines:**

```
int *p = (int *) &s;  
*p=10;
```

**Main Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class sample {
private:
  int a;
public:
  void function () {
    a=5;
  }
  void printA () {
    cout<<"value is "<<a<<endl;
  }
};

int main () {
  sample s;
  s.function();
  s.printA();

  int *p = (int *) &s;
  *p=10;

  s.printA();
}
```

Comment: you just simply can add there any virtual method and at VS and gcc "a" will not be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `(int*)` there is a really really bad idea. You are using a class, that isn't an int, as an int. Which is bad.

You can't access private members, and you shouldn't, that's why they are private.

```
int *p = (int *) &s;  
*p=10;
```

This means, you have an object `s`, of type `sample`, and it has a data member `int a;`. What you wrote works, because `a` happens to be at the beginning of the class.

There are some cases where the layout of a class is guaranteed, you can read about it here:

- [What are POD types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)
- [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821)

Answer (score 2):

First off, please never do this.

You're exploiting the memory layout of the class `sample`. The first member is an `int` and it resides at the start of the class' memory space.

Try adding another `int` before `a` and you'll see that a is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

This code is trying to access the member `a` in class `sample` by breaking the encapsulation imposed by class with the help of pointer casting. It is **not safe**, coz it depends on the memory layout of class members.

The assumption is that, the member `a` will be at the starting position of a `sample` object, so taking the address of the object, and casting it to `int*` will make it possible to access the first `int` member.

This is working because `a` is indeed in the first position, but this is not guaranteed and will not work for other members due to padding/alignment and in case of inheritance hierarchy. This type of code is dangerous.

You should have accessors/mutators of private members if required, instead of writing this kind of code access them.

Comment: "this is not guaranteed" - yes it is (since C++11), unless you change the class so it's no longer standard-layout. I agree that it's dangerous, since such a change would silently break the code; but you can (portably) depend on the layout of such a class if you really need to.